# Firebase function with express works fine in local emulator but fails on the deployed version

Tags: firebase, function, express

index.js file

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const {onRequest} = require("firebase-functions/v2/https");
const logger = require("firebase-functions/logger");
const admin = require("firebase-admin");
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");
const express = require("express");

const app = express();
admin.initializeApp();
const db = admin.firestore();

const runtimeOpts = {
  maxInstances: 10,
};

app.post("/", bodyParser.urlencoded({extended:true}), async (request, response) => {
  try {
    logger.info("Request received BodyContent: " + request.body);
    response.status(200);
  } catch (error) {
    logger.error(error);
    response.status(500).send("Something went wrong");
  }
});

exports.smsEntry = functions.runWith(runtimeOpts).https.onRequest(app);
```

All dependancies are included in package.json file, I tried to run this function with local emulator and it works perfectly fine but when deployed and invoked function starts execution but fails in few seconds. There are no error details reported in logs. It seems like execution never entered in function.

screenshot of logs

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wHsPe.png)

tried with multiple approaches and searching on stack overflow but none worked.